# Как на R импортировать csv с выбором кодировки текста?

Tags: csv, r

Есть CSV. При импорте с помощью readr :: read_csv2 () - текст загружается в другой кодировке. Как это пофиксить? Выбрать кодировку текста? или просто функции по декодировке?

Comment: вы в консоли вызываете или в чём-нибудь типа rstudio? если в консоли — см. мой ответ, если в какой-нибудь программе — то см. настройки программы относительно локалей/кодировок.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Еще сработал такой вариант

```
read.csv2("data.csv", fileEncoding = "Windows-1251")
```

Answer (score 1):

у функций `readr::read_*()` есть параметр `locale`, которому можно передать вывод функции `readr::locale()`, вызванной с нужными параметрами.

пример:

```
> readr::read_csv2("dos.csv",locale=readr::locale(encoding="cp1251"))
```

Comment: Спасибо! Сработало